# A Java array with all the words in the English language? (or something with the same effect)

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary

Pretty much, I'm writing a program that will run the same code on each word in an array. I have made an array with about 50 words just to try it, and it works great.
Does anyone know of a way to get all words in the English Language (or at least a fairly large amount, like the contents of a Dictionary) into a Java array?

Thanks in advance for any replies!

Comment: array is not a good place to store a disctionary. OR read from file in parts.

Comment: Well, if you can get a list of all those words (which can get quite huge) you just put them into the array/set/map. The questions here are: Where do you get that list? How would you handle plurals, different spellings, tense (lose -> lost) etc.? And most importantly, what's your goal with this?

Comment: Use the `java.io` API to read [this file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/examples/dictionary.txt) into your app. Put each line you read into a new `ArrayList` element. Vuala!

Comment: It's not really a problem about what the words ARE (it's not a program that writes a story for example), i just need a MASSIVE amount of words. How would I keep all the words in a text file, and then take each word, temporarily load it into a string, then take the next one (haven't done much file I/O stuff in java)?

Comment: Is your problem winding large lists of words or loading this lists into an array?

Comment: Mostly the turning-the-whole-thing-into-something-my-program-can-use part. :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't see nowaq's comment :) Nowaq: I haven't done much File I/O in Java, how would I read a line from that file? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having large amount of "words" in the array will be highly inefficient. But if your purpose is just experimenting, you can

- Copy large amount of text in a text file.
- Read the contents of that text file into a string
- Tokenize/Split the string contents on whitespace

Comment: Hi, how would I read the contents of a text file that has a new word on each line? (I haven't done much file I/O in Java yet)

Comment: @evemzee see this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035894/fastest-way-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-with-2-sets-of-strings-on-each-line

Answer (score 4):

On linux you can do this. It includes a lot of "words" I am not sure is English.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader("/usr/share/dict/words");
Set<String> words = new LinkedHashSet();
String line;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) words.add(line);
br.close();
```

Comment: oooooops: `$ ls /usr/share/dict/words
ls: cannot access /usr/share/dict/words: No such file or directory`

Comment: You are best using your own dictionary in any case. :)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from being a inefficient data structure to hold dictionary data, Arrays can hold duplicates. So, if you are adding words to the Array, are you sure you aren't adding duplicates? ..If you are checking for duplicates, that adds an other layer of code complexity, which increases the [run-time/algo complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms) and decreases the performance.

Answer (score 1):

It's an excellent question for which there are two methods:

1. Open a dictionary, and type out every damn word!
2. Write a program that accepts a word from the user and stores it after categorizing it, into an array.

Both methods are quite tedious, but at least with the second one, you won't have to do everything yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

The [Word List project](http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/) on source forge has a bunch of lists you could use.

Answer (score 0):

You've said in the comments that

> It's not really a problem about what the words ARE (it's not a program that writes a story 
>   for example), i just need a MASSIVE amount of words

Do they have to be *words*, or could you just use randomly generated combinations of letters and/or digits instead?  You haven't clarified your true objective - if you just want to experiment with IO and arrays, then you don't need *real* data.