# Reading scanned words into an array using Scanner import in Java

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I have this code:

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter file name: ");
        File file = new File(input.nextLine());
        if (file.length() == 0) {
            System.out.println("The input file is empty.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
```

It reads the file that a user has typed in and then checks to see if it is empty or not, pretty simple.

What I want to do is put each word from this file into a string array that will contain each word, punctuation and all (an apostrophe or a dash would be included as the word). How do I do this?

We are assuming that the file contents may look something like this:

```
it's
Stop

the

malformed yes-man
```

Just random words either separated by returns or spaces.

Your help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Open the file. Read its content line by line and then save the content in array of String.

Comment: file reading is wrong. Use a `FileReader`. Read each line, split it based on `space`, and keep adding the results to your master array. Done

Comment: you can also use next() instead of nextLine() to get one word at a time.

Comment: I was told I could simple just scan the words out of the file from the beginning of the scanner function. Can I still do this if I have it as a user input?

Comment: For reading file example. Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035894/fastest-way-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-with-2-sets-of-strings-on-each-line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this (example using BufferedReader and not Scanner) This will give you idea and then you could implement you own using Scanner :)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ReadFile
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter file name");
        String fileName = br.readLine();
        File file = new File(fileName);
        if(file.length() == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("File is empty");
        }
        else
        {
            BufferedReader fr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
            String[] line;
            String str;
            while((str=fr.readLine()) != null)
            {
                line = str.split(" ");
                for(String word : line)
                    words.add(word);
            }

            // Printing the content of words
            for(String word : words)
                System.out.println(word);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: THAT is VERY helpful. I was actually attempting to use the bufferreader in the first place, but we in my class are not familiar with it so we all resorted to scanner. The professor assumes we know java, but most of us have no java experience and reading files is the first thing we had to learn to do, and on our own no less because he would not teach it to us in class.

Comment: Happy to help you :) For understanding the concept, first google for the basic example and then look into the API. It's very simple, you would love it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] words = input.split("(?s)\\s+");
```

Comment: I feel like I should intuitively know what to do with this, but I don't know what to do this with. I am not very good at java and the concept of opening files is new and so is reading them. We were not formally taught how to do this in my class, merely told to do it as though it were a known thing amongst me and my classmates. This is not the case. So please, I'm slighly embarassed to ask, but how do I read the file into this array concept that you have given me?

Comment: Are you allowed to use 3rd party libraries? (Fyi That is the way it's done in the industry)

Comment: I can't say that I know if we do. It is likely we do not however.