# Fastest way to read from file line by line in Java

Tags: java

What is the fastest way to read and parse line by line from file, if I need to have randomaccess to my file. I want to seek from one positon to another one and parse lines between these positions.

Comment: I have already answered this question. Take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035894/fastest-way-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-with-2-sets-of-strings-on-each-line/5035998#5035998

Comment: [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)

Comment: @AlexR op needs random access to the file!

Comment: I am using RandomAccessFile but it works slow, when I am parsing huge number of lines!

Comment: Reading lines and random access are mutually exclusive unless all the lines are the same length.

Comment: @EJP Please have a look at my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Channels` provided by NIO package to read files line by line or randomly.
But here is a caveat:

`BufferedReader` allows your to read files line by line but it accesses them as records rather than as blocks. So there is no random access.
`FileChannel` and its children line `SeekableByteChannel` and `WritableByteChannel` allow random read and write but you cannot read line by line. Well, you can if you know how many bytes are there in one line. In channels, you can read the same data as bytes or as chars. Nothing can prevent you from doing that.

So, make a decision :)

Here is the tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html

Jacob Jenkov has a good comparison between NIO and IO package: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/nio-vs-io.html